# Best way to implement calling a constructor from another constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, instantiation

### The Setup

- I have a class that is created with a FileInfo parameter (lets call this MyFileClass)
- I have another scenario where if a URL and description are passed in as strings, it will create a file and then it should essentially create the MyFileClass with the FileInfo object of the file it just created.

I imagined it would look something like:

```
public MyFileClass(FileInfo info)
{
    //do things 
}

public MyFileClass (string url, string Description)
{
    // var tempfile = FileInfo that results from creating file 
    MyFileClass(tempfile)
}
```

### Question

What is the proper way to implement this idea? I've got the file creation part down, just not quite sure of the syntax for making it work in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a static method to create the FileInfo.

```
public class MyFileClass
{
    public MyFileClass(FileInfo info)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public MyFileClass(string url, string description)
        : this(GetFileInfo(url, description))
    { 
        // do more work
    }

    static FileInfo GetFileInfo(string url, string description)
    {
        return new FileInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I see! I vaguely understood the call to this but with the additional method it makes all the sense in the world. Thanks!